# Functions that call multiple other functions (efficiency)

Tags: c, function-call, memory-efficient

I am building a simple program that simulates logic circuits with functions.
I have already made a OR function and an inverter function.

I can now simulate a NOR gate two ways:
I can have the NOR function call the OR and inverter functions and combine them.
Or I can write new code for the NOR function specifically.

Which is more efficient?
Is it bad practice to have one call two other functions every time I call my NOR function?
Or should I avoid having to write new code by using the code I already have when possible?

Comment: It is better to reuse whatever you already had. You already tested and coded `NOT` and `OR`. (Re)Use them now.

Comment: I guess a bit more context would be much better.

Comment: Since the NOR gate is one of the "universal" gates (along with NAND), I would implement it directly, and if re-use is a concern, use it to build other gates.

Comment: The difference in efficiency between calling `or` then `not` versus `nor` is probably minuscule. I doubt you'll observe without detailed measurements a difference in performance. Whether you have `nor` on its own really just depends upon what your own goals are in your simulation. If you want to simulate a circuit and have `nor` be an "atomic" gate (which does exist in electronics), then sure, it can be its own function, and likewise you can define `nand`.

Comment: Most CPU architectures have all of the logic functions like those built into the ALU.  By separating `NOT` and `OR` functions rather than just writing a simple `NOR` function, you're likely to kill any chance of your compiler optimizing it to just use `NOR` instruction.